# How to find out all the files in other machines using bash shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to find out which files are in `machineB` and which files are in `machineC`.

And I need to run my shell script on `machineA` to figure out which files are in `machineB` and which files are in `machineC`

I have around 300 files distributed in `machineB` and `machineC`.

Now I would like to find out which file is in which machine `(machineB or machineC)`.

Below is my shell script which I am running on `machineA` and `PRIMARY_PARTITION` has some file numbers and `SECONDARY_PARTITION` has some file numbers. And the files are present in this directory -

```
/data/snapshot/20140317
```

in `machineB` or `machineC` .. And the file path is like this -

```
t1_1980_0_200003_5.data
t1_1980_3_200003_5.data
t1_1980_5_200003_5.data
t1_1980_7_200003_5.data
t1_1980_9_200003_5.data
```

Here the file number is 0, 3, 5, 7, 9. Other names in the `filename` are always going to be same apart from the file numbers.

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION=/data/snapshot
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(0 3 5 7 9)
SECONDARY_PARTITION=(1 2 4 6 8)

dir1=20140317
dir2=20140317

echo $dir1
echo $dir2

if [ "$dir1" = "$dir2" ]
then
    for el in "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
    do
        # do something here may be?
    done
    for sl in "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}"
    do
        # do something here may be?
    done
fi
```

Now my question is how would I find out all the files in `machineB` and `machineC`. Meaning out of `(0 3 5 7 9)` and `(1 2 4 6 8)` which files are in `machineB` and which are in `machineC`.

As an example I have shown very small set of files above. In general, I have lot of files which I am thinking its pretty difficult for me to login in machineB and machineC to find out the files.

Comment: Why not rsync?.

Comment: @Braiam: I haven't worked with rsync before so there will be some learning curve for me. I would like to learn it but given the time frame I have, I thought its best to do using `ssh`.

Comment: [rsync can work over ssh just fine](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html) and seems easy too. Now, depending of what your final goal is rsync can in a single command do it (which may not be helpful if you are doing an assignment)

Comment: @Braiam: It's not an assignment. I need to do this on our production system. I can try using rsync for this. Can you provide an example if possible? And do I need to install something on our production servers on machineA? bcoz from machineA I will be running my shell script.

Comment: @SSH I would use `rsync` or a [tar pipe over ssh](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-tar-command-through-network-over-ssh-session/).

Comment: Are there any files you need to avoid? If not, why not just copy everything? `scp user@machine1:/data/snapshot/20140317*200003_5.data .` and `scp user@machine2:/data/snapshot/20140317*200003_5.data .` . Please clarify your question, explain how you connect to these machines andwhy you can't use a simple glob as I suggest.

Comment: @terdon: I don't need to copy files. I am trying to find out which files are in `machineB` and which are in `machineC`.

Comment: In that case, please [edit] your question, the opening paragraph is very misleading, you state that your problem is that you need to _copy_ files to machineA but don't know if they are on C or B. Are you trying to figure out which file came from which _after_ having successfully copied them (which begs the question of why not before)? How do you connect to the machines? Can you simply do `ssh user@machineB ls /path` and collect the files that way?

Comment: @terdon: Point noted. Edited the question. Sorry about that.. I am connecting it using `ssh` since I have lot of files how do I find out which one are in which machines is causing me problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 approaches that I can think of off the top of my head. The first would involve using `rsync` the second would be to use a combination of `ssh` & `diff`.

**NOTE:** Both of these approaches would compare a directory on machineA that has all the files with a subset of these files on machine's B and C showing you which machine (B or C) was the originator of said files.

#### Example data

Say I had the following setup of files on machineA.

```
$ ls
t1_1980_10_200003_5.data  t1_1980_4_200003_5.data  t1_1980_8_200003_5.data
t1_1980_1_200003_5.data   t1_1980_5_200003_5.data  t1_1980_9_200003_5.data
t1_1980_2_200003_5.data   t1_1980_6_200003_5.data
t1_1980_3_200003_5.data   t1_1980_7_200003_5.data
```

#### Method #1 - rsync

Now let's find out what files in this directory came from machineB.

```
$ rsync --dry-run -avz machineB:~/20140317/ .
receiving incremental file list
./
t1_1980_1_200003_5.data
t1_1980_2_200003_5.data
t1_1980_3_200003_5.data
t1_1980_4_200003_5.data
t1_1980_5_200003_5.data

sent 29 bytes  received 165 bytes  129.33 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

While machineC:

```
$ rsync --dry-run -avz machineC:~/20140317/ .
receiving incremental file list
./
t1_1980_10_200003_5.data
t1_1980_6_200003_5.data
t1_1980_7_200003_5.data
t1_1980_8_200003_5.data
t1_1980_9_200003_5.data

sent 29 bytes  received 166 bytes  390.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

#### Method #2 - ssh + diff

As an alternative you can use some semi-basic `ssh` and `diff` to do something similar.

```
$ cd /dir/with/machBC
$ diff -B <(ssh user@machineB "ls -R ~/20140317/") <(ls -R .)
> .:
> t1_1980_10_200003_5.data
> t1_1980_6_200003_5.data
> t1_1980_7_200003_5.data
> t1_1980_8_200003_5.data
> t1_1980_9_200003_5.data
```

Comment: What is `/dir1/` here in your example for rsync?

Comment: I am confuse what is `/dir1/` here? This folder `20140317` is in `machineB` and `machineC` not `machineA`. And the files are inside this folder  `20140317`.

Comment: @SSH - it was just as directory that I was using for my simulation of your problem, I've replaced it with your `20140317`.

Comment: Sure.. In your ssh + diff example. I would be running that diff command on `machineA` where the files are located right? If yes, then what is this path `cd /dir/with/machBC`?

Comment: @SSH = correct, on machineA. That's a path to denote that this is some location on machineA with the files from machine's B & C.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (big if), I would do it with something like this running on machineA:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file_pattern='t1_1980_*_200003_5.data';
target_dir='/data/snapshot/20140317/'
## Save the files from each machine into bash array
files_on_B=$(ssh user@machineB find "$target_dir" -name "$file_pattern")
files_on_C=$(ssh user@machineC find "$target_dir" -name "$file_pattern")

## Do whatever you like with them, here I am simply printing
echo "Files from B: ${files_on_B[@]}"
echo "Files from C: ${files_on_C[@]}"
```

Note that the script assumes sane file names, like in your example, with no spaces, new lines or other strange characters.

Comment: Thanks terdon. I am suppose to run this script from machineA where the files are located.. Right?

Comment: @SSH yes, from machineA.